# "this.hide(); is not a function" calling a method in a class

Tags: jquery

I have the following code :

```
var Modal = Class.extend({
    //--- Default options
    defaults: {
        width: 300,
        height: 200
        // . . . more options
    },

    //--- Initialize the Modal class
    init: function (options) {
        //--- Extend defaults and options
        this.options = jQuery.extend(this.defaults, options);
    },

    //--- Create the Modal
    create: function () {

            // . . . code removed

            var closeButton = document.createElement("div");
            jQuery(closeButton)
                .attr({ "class": "modal_close" })
                .css({ "cursor": "pointer" })
                .live("click", function () {
                    this.closeModal();
                })
                .appendTo(modalHead);

            // . . . more code
    },

    //--- Hide the Modal
    closeModal: function () {
        // TODO : Code to hide the modal
        jQuery("#modal_container").fadeOut(200).remove();
        jQuery("#lean_overlay").fadeOut(200).remove();
    }
});
```

Now when I in the click event in the create method try to call the delete method i get this error :

```
this.closeModal(); is not a function
```

what am I missing here?

**EDIT :** Changed the hide function to be closeModal just to simplify my question

Comment: `$(this).hide`, since `this` is a DOM object and `hide` is a jQuery function.

Comment: Edited my question because it is not the jQuery function "hide()" but the one in my class ;o)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace `this.hide();` with `$(this).hide();`

Later edit:

Keep a reference to `this` before entering `.live()`

```
create: function () {
        // . . . code removed

        var closeButton = document.createElement("div");
        var myModal = this; 
        jQuery(closeButton)
            .attr({ "class": "modal_close" })
            .css({ "cursor": "pointer" })
            .live("click", function () {
                myModal.closeModal();
            })
            .appendTo(modalHead);

        // . . . more code
},
```

Comment: I guess OP wants to call `Modal.prototype.hide` not `jQuery.prototype.hide`.

Comment: Yes it is the the function in my class I want to call and your suggestion works, but can I somehow set tis in the init function so that it could work throughout the whole class?

Answer (score 0):

This issue arises from the fact that jQuery has bound the DOM element the event has been raised against to `this`. To get around this just use the following

```
.live('click', this.closeModal)
```

If you want to cache a reference to the current instance of `Modal` in the `init` `function` you can do something like:

```
init: function () {
    this.me = this;
}
```

When referencing it just remember to use `this.me` (not just `me`).

Comment: You are right, thats what i want to do and it would be nice to be able to set it in the init function but your example does not work. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately you won't be able to use `this.me` as jQuery will bind `this` to the DOM element which has been clicked. You can get round this my using something like: `.live('click', this.closeModal)`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clearing that. Then I think it's better to do it with a declared variable as mentioned by gabitzish

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.live('click', $.proxy(this, 'hide'))
```